# How to call an Url image into a single row fragment for a Listview?

Tags: java, android, url, imageview, drawable

I have this code here. At the moment I call the same stock image over and over again. What I would like to do, is for each `Drawable` item in the `images[]` array is to call different URL images if there is an internet connection, but if not, call the stock drawable image.

I have just compiled Glide into my app to try there are no errors that i can see but the pic seams to stay as the stock image. Is there anybody who can help me figure this one out please. thanks for all the help guys

```
    public class CastingAppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;

ArrayList<SingleRow> list;


CastingAppsAdapter(Context c) {



    context = c;


    list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();



    Resources res = c.getResources();
    String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.castingapptitles);
    String[] discriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.castingappdiscriptions);
    int[] images = {R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo1, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo, R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo,};
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

        list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i], discriptions[i], images[i]));


    }

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_castingapps, viewGroup, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

    TextView discription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvDiscription);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivRowimage);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load("http://www.androidfannetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/AllCast-Logo.png")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo)
            .into(image);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load("hhttp://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41On5fieMAL.png")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo1)
            .into(image);

    SingleRow temp = list.get(i);
    title.setText(temp.title);
    discription.setText(temp.discription);
    image.setImageResource(temp.image);


    return row;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get UrlImage to drawable, I think it will works on your code!

You could try with `Glide`, here's a tutorial to show you the differences between `Glide` and `Picasso`: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Firstly, set up on your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

and then this code, hope it helps!

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load("UrlImage")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.yourDrawable)
    .into(imageViewPlaceholder);
```

Comment: i have added this but it doesnt seam to be working for me lol. ive added the new code above for you to look at. there were no errors in the code. but it just stays as the stock png. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you set up the internet permissions on your Manifest? Are you connected to a network? I know that it takes a few seconds... but It should be working. I'm watching this example: https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-listadapter-listview-gridview and It seems that your code is OK

Comment: i already use internet permissions. and internet not an issue. im baffled lol.

Comment: sorted thanks deleted the drawables and used the string url list from the blog you shared thanks again been a massive help

Answer (score 0):

you can use ImageRequest in Volley 
it can download image and cache it for you

use this link: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html